# Why could Jung Ui-myeong not leave his body?

Tags: sweet-home

In the second season of *Sweet Home*, "Jung Ui-myeong" seems to be going around in the body of Sang-uk. On at least two occasions, when the body is injured, he tries to abandon it, but fails to do. He seems to be rather frustrated with this limitation.

Of course, a possible out-of-universe reason might have been a desire to keep Sang-uk's actor around, or limited availability of the actor playing "Ui-myeong," but there is clearly a reason within the show. What is it?